# Install Ubuntu on MacBook Pro (2011) from Windows Desktop

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, macbook

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an SSD from my Windows Desktop so that the SSD can be placed into my MacBook and boot into Ubuntu. I've been researching and trying various methods the past few days, but to no success.

Details:

- The SSD is new, and as such doesn't have OS X on it. I am looking to install Ubuntu without installing OS X first.
- When I acquired the MacBook it exhibited the signs of needing a hard drive cable replacement. (Steps found at https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Cable+Replacement/10379)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Could you share some more detail about what you've already tried?

Comment: Thanks! I've tried installing Ubuntu onto the SSD (from my windows machine) and putting it back into the MacBook, I have a Live USB which allows me to boot into Ubuntu on the MacBook, but not install to the SSD.

Comment: ...so *did* you replace the hard drive cable? if it's broken, that might explain why the hard drive can't be seen. In any case, let us know how it works out if you try it from a CD/DVD.

Comment: Yes, I did replace the cable. When I tried the CD/DVD, i was still unable to install to the SSD :/ My next plan is to try getting an OS X Bootable USB to see if I can get anything onto the SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more prone to Debian, but for a MacbookPro of the era that still has a CD/DVD drive in it, put the blank SSD in the MacBookPro, stuff in a LiveCD or LiveDVD install disk, and press C when powering on. Machines without a CD/DVD are more of a pain, or require an external CD/DVD drive or getting a USB thumb drive installer to behave (which I personally find chancier than the discs, so far.)

It's far more difficult to install for hardware OTHER than the hardware you are working on (ie, all the various bits of the windows machine .vs. all the various different bits needing different drivers of the Mac.) If you boot into the machine you are going to install for, it's much easier to let the installer figure out what drivers are needed.

With Debian, anyway, it's often the case that a wired ethernet connection is needed until you can go pick up the WiFi drivers from the non-free distributions - I gather that Ubuntu may be less hard-core about this, but it still may help, depending what they have on their CD images.

I have recently been loading Debian on a LOT of older macs that can no longer be updated in MacOS, and what is or is not on the internal disk is never a factor.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there a reason that using the LiveCD works more consistently than a Live USB? (I have had the same experience where my Live USB cannot access the SSD)

Comment: I don't really know - I just find that I have better results booting from a disc than from a thumb-drive, and until I have no choice, I've stopped bothering to try to make bootable thumb-drives that behave. YMMV.